# In Premiere Pro, how can I delete clip portions that are between these labels?

Tags: premiere

In Premiere Pro, how can I delete clip portions that are between these labels?

(in an automatic way that's not too manual)

[image]

One way I could do it that is a bit slow and manual, is SHIFT-DOWN gets to e.g. where the cursor is in the image below.  'i' (to put a left mark in), then SHIFT-DOWN, then 'o', (to put a right marker in), then Ctrl-Shift-A to deselect the clip. Then shift-delete (rippled delete). And just keep repeating those keystrokes.  for all 40ish labels. But i'm hoping there's a quicker way.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a dirty yet maybe effective method:

1. Create an adjustment-layer above your two video tracks, that goes from start to end.
2. Select all your pink labels and drag them up, effectively replacing those parts in the adjustment-layer.
3. Delete your still selected labels
4. Pull down the bits of the adjustment-layer into your main clip and delete them.

If I were to show this method to my testers in the final exam they'd probably chop my head off, but it's the easiest way I came up with so far.